# infinitive or present continuous?

Tags: verbs, verb-forms

Which is correct?

- To get there - and stay there - you will need to be creative as well as efficient, and constantly proving yourself.

or

- To get there - and stay there - you will need to be creative as well as efficient, and constantly prove yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, both make sense.

> To get there - and stay there - you will need to **be** *creative* as well as *efficient*, and constantly ***proving*** yourself.

In the sentence above you say that someone needs to be proving themselves. The structure is *be + adjective + adjective + present participle*. In other words, be creative, be efficient, and be proving yourself (it's the Present Continuous form).

> To get there - and stay there - you will need to **be** creative as well as efficient, and constantly **prove** yourself.

In the sentence above, using 2 verbs, you say not what the person should be like, but what they should **do**: be creative and efficient, and prove yourself. So, this person needs to do 2 things, and have 2 qualities - creativity and efficiency.

Personally, I'd use the second sentence.

Comment: That is what I thought too, many thanks!